# Next previous link click jquery

Tags: jquery

I've a list of product thumbnails below a featured image.

What I'm trying to do, is that when either the next or previous button is clicked which are present inside the featured image, the next and previous image in the thumbnail list should appear as the featured image.

Basically every product thumbnail appears underneath the featured image as a manually advanced slide show.

Here is the URL to check out what I'm trying to achieve.
[site](http://www.imagefix.co.uk/toprace_dem/product/3d-tumbling-ladybug-4-axis-4-ch-rc-remote-control-quad-copter-rtf/)

Below is the code I'm trying to use:

```
var slide_list_siblings =jQuery('.product_thumbnails li a').map(function()
    {return jQuery(this).get()});

var slide_list_array = slide_list_siblings;

var slide_list_start = slide_list_siblings[0];

var slide_list_next =slide_list_array[(jQuery.inArray(slide_list_start, slide_list_array) + 1) % slide_list_array.length];

var slide_list_prev = slide_list_array[(jQuery.inArray(slide_list_start, slide_list_array) - 1 + slide_list_array.length) % slide_list_array.length];


jQuery('a#product_thumbnails_next').click(function(event) {
slide_list_next.click();
});

jQuery('a#product_thumbnails_prev').click(function(event) {
slide_list_prev.click();
});
```

Comment: Please use capitalization and punctuation in your question. No one likes to read a wall of words.

Comment: not sure what this means: `below is code i'm using it currently works once any help appreciated !!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same `slide_list_next` and `slide_list_prev` after the first click but they still point to the same objects, the second and the last items from the list .

The following code will track the currently selected item

```
(function(){    
  var thumbs = jQuery('.product_thumbnails li a');
  var thumbs_count = thumbs.length;
  var current_index = 0;

  // Track the currently selected item, so that clicking on the thumbnails
  // Doesn't mess up our current_index
  thumbs.click(function(){
      current_index = thumbs.index(this);    
  });

  // on clicking next button
  jQuery('a#product_thumbnails_next').click(function(event) {
    current_index++;
    // wrap around
    current_index = current_index % thumbs_count;
    thumbs[current_index].click();
  });

  //  on clicking on prev button
  jQuery('a#product_thumbnails_prev').click(function(event) {
    current_index--;
    // wrap around
    current_index = (current_index + thumbs_count) % thumbs_count;
    thumbs[current_index].click();
  });    
})();
```

I strongly suggest you move the arrows to the top because having them move every time you click on an item is really annoying. The other option is making sure the images have the same height.